# ng-transclude works differently for element and attribute directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

**Case I:**

I have a directive(lets call it 'x') with element level restriction 'E' transcluded inside a directive(lets call it 'y') with isolate scope. 'y' has two nested ng-repeats' in the template.

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/hudani/edit?html,js,output

**Behaviour:** 'x' takes the parent scope of 'y' that is the controller scope (expected behaviour as some call sibling scope)

**Case II:**

I have a directive(lets call it 'x') with attribute level restriction 'A' transcluded inside a directive(lets call it 'y') with isolate scope. 'y' has two nested ng-repeats' in the template.

**JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/monoco/2/edit?html,js,output

**Behaviour:** The transcluded content has the 2nd ng-repeat as the sibling scope and first ng-repeat as the parent scope.

Please suggest some resources to affirm this behaviour and if possible provide some insights into the different behaviours shown by different restrictions on the enclosed directive('x').